# How to minimize the deviation?

Tags: java

I wrote a program which clicks on a button at a specific time. This button sends a request to the server (I don't own this server) which will output an arrival time.

This arrival time includes milliseconds, so each millisecond is worth a lot.

At first I ping the server (in this example I pinged google) and get the latency. Because I just need the travel time to the server, I divide it by 2. Then Robot bot (the clickbot) clicks the button at the specific time which has the format: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS

Unfortunately, I have a really high deviation between this program and the arrival time. This is what I want to optimize.
If I optimize it manually, then I get an average deviation of 30 milliseconds, but I always need to adapt it manually each time I want to use it.

So the deviation constantly changes. Now I want to adapt the program so that I no longer have to adapt it manually. I want to achieve the minimum deviation without manually interaction.

How can I achieve this? I have already synchronized with the server's time server, so my program should have the same time as the server that sends me the arrival time.

What else should I consider? I already have considered the latency and the server time.

**Edit:** Yes, it is possible to "dry fire" the button, but I don't know how to do it. At the moment I try to learn it, but it is still difficult for me.

@Joachim Sauer you mean "dry fire" with a post request, right?

@Joop Eggen Ok. If I click a button, then the server gets the request and outputs the arrival time.
Now I imitate the click with "robot bot" and calculate the latency/2 to get as close as possible to the arrival time I want to have (arrival time I want to have = "date = dateFormatter.parse("2020-08-28 23:51:50.000");" in this example).

Now when I adapt the timer/date manually, I still have a deviation around 30 milliseconds. If I don't adapt it manually, I will have a deviation of 700+ milliseconds.

So I want to have the smallest deviation possible without manually adapting the timer/date. But how can I achieve this? I already have considered the latency and the server time.

```
package Timen;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import org.apache.commons.net.ntp.NTPUDPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ntp.TimeInfo;


public class timeclick {
   
    //The task which you want to execute
    private static class MyTimeTask extends TimerTask
    {

        public void run()      
        {
            Robot bot;
            try {
                bot = new Robot();
                bot.mouseMove(611, 529);
                bot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
                bot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
               
            } catch (AWTException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           
        }
    }

        public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
                   
             // create the ping command as a list of strings
            timeclick ping = new timeclick();
             List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
             commands.add("ping");
             commands.add("111.222.33.4");
             double latencyToServer=ping.doCommand(commands);
         
            //convert String into int
            int latencyToServer1 = (int)latencyToServer;
            int allDelays= (latencyToServer1) /2;
            System.out.println("All deviations: "+allDelays);
           
           
               
             //the Date and time at which you want to execute  
            DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
            Date date;
            try {
                date = dateFormatter.parse("2020-08-28 23:51:50.000");
                System.out.println ("current time " + dateFormatter.format(date));
                Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar1.setTime(date);
                calendar1.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, -allDelays);
                date = calendar1.getTime();
                System.out.println ("new time     " + dateFormatter.format(date));
                //Now create the time and schedule it
                Timer timer = new Timer();
    
                //Use this if you want to execute it once
                timer.schedule(new MyTimeTask(), date);
               
                //Use this if you want to execute it repeatedly
                //int period = 10000;//10secs
                //timer.schedule(new MyTimeTask(), date, period );
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           
           
           
          }
    
          public double doCommand(List<String> command)
          throws IOException
          {
            String s = null;
    
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
            Process process = pb.start();
            Process process1 = pb.start();
    
            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader stdInput1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process1.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
           
           
    
           
            // read the output from the command
            System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
            while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null)
            {
              System.out.println(s);
            }
         
           
            // read any errors from the attempted command
            System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
            while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null)
            {
              System.out.println(s);
            }
       
            //get the average latency
            System.out.println("here is the average latency :\n");      
            double latency = 0.0;
            while ((s = stdInput1.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if (s.contains("Mittelwert")) {
                    String timeWithValue = s.split(" = ")[2];
                    String value = timeWithValue.split("ms")[0];
                    latency = Double.parseDouble(value);
                    System.out.println("latency " + latency);
                }
             
            }
            return latency;
           
    
    
    
         
        }
       
    }
```

Comment: Can you "dry fire" the button for the calibration? Is there some cost associated with doing the request? Because measuring the deviation between your expected result and the server-reported one probably allows for better automatic detection and correction of the time deviation.

Comment: Sorry I did not entirely understand all, and would need a stepwise explanation (for dummies). Maybe others have the same difficulty?

Comment: Why are you using java.util.Calender, when you can use the java.time package? What is "deviation"? Are you trying to send your command at the same rate of the delay, so you send a command right as the previous command returns? What is the "deviation" in request time. It could be greater than 30ms so you'd never really get better than what you're doing.